# Find radius and height

Tags: geometry, circles, puzzle

I have the following problem: given the length of the chord AB and the length of the arc AB, find the radius of the circle and the height of the triangle ACB where C is a point on the circle such that the height has the maximum length (I mean C is the "most extreme point - the distance from C to AB is maximum as in the figure - the point C is where I wrote $L_{AB}=84$). Any solution? Thanks! Lenth of chord = 74, length of arc=84.
[image]

Comment: what have you tried? since this is inded a puzzle it would be nice to hear your attempts here...

Comment: I have 0 attempts...lack of ideas :D

Comment: is Center=Origin ?

Comment: The center is the point O

Comment: Why didn't you write "C" there?

Comment: because I missed it...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: let $\theta$ be the angle $AOB$. Then $R\theta = L_{AB}=84$ and $2R\sin(\theta/2)=AB=74$.

Height of triangle $ACB$ is $R-R\cos(\theta/2)$.

Comment: what is R*THETHA?

Comment: length of arc of radius R subtending angle $\theta$ at the centre

Answer (score 0):

Your 'extreme height of a triangle' is called an arc's **sagitta**.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagitta_(geometry)

Comment: That's not an answer, its a comment.

Comment: This is a most precise answer I can give without doing someone else's homework. The answer is there, in the page linked, it's half line long and certainly doesn't need to be copied here.